# NameError when assigning input() to variable (Python2.7.11)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get a name error even though I'm just trying to put a string into a variable.

I am trying to do this on Python 2.7.11. Does anyone have anything that helps? Upgrading Python is not an option for me.

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in " ":
            translation = translation + "@"
result = (input("enter a phrase you want encrypted: "))
result = translate(result)
```

This is the error that's shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\hello\encrydecry\encryption1.py", line 158, in <module
>
    result = (input("enter a phrase you want encrypted: "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, when you use `input()`, Python interprets the input. So when you type `hello`, `hello` is interpreted as a variable, and you're essentially doing `result = hello`. Hence the error `NameError: name 'hello' is not defined`.

One option is to simply type the input between quotes, so it will be interpreted as a string: `'hello'`.

To avoid the input being interpreted altogether, you have to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`, which doesn't interpret the user input and always returns a string:

```
result = raw_input("enter a phrase you want encrypted: ")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in " ":
            translation = translation + "@"
result =raw_input("enter a phrase you want encrypted: ")
result = translate(result)
```

Comment: Please explain how this code addresses OP's issue.

Comment: Please add an explanation, not just a code dump.